# Google drive api keeps requesting authentication whenever my script is run

Tags: python, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client

I am trying to create a script that uploads pictures to my google drive folder. This script works well on my computer, but the problem is that this script is supposed to run itself every other week automatically, but right now, whenever I run the script google prompts me to log in, instead of remembering the session from the first time I logged in.

my script to push the pictures to google drive looks like this:

```
def upload_files():
    upload_files_list = []
    for element in os.listdir("billeder"):
        upload_files_list.append("/root/billeder/" + element)

    for upload_file in upload_files_list:
        gfile = drive.CreateFile({'parents': [{'id': 'folder_id_here'}]})
        # Read file and set it as the content of this instance.
        gfile.SetContentFile(upload_file)
        gfile.Upload()  # Upload the file.
```

my script to authenticate looks like this:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import os.path

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly']


def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Drive v3 API.
    Prints the names and ids of the first 10 files the user has access to.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the firstp
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'client_secrets.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    try:
        service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

        # Call the Drive v3 API
        results = service.files().list(
            pageSize=10, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
        items = results.get('files', [])

        if not items:
            print('No files found.')
            return
        print('Files:')
        for item in items:
            print(u'{0} ({1})'.format(item['name'], item['id']))
    except HttpError as error:
        # TODO(developer) - Handle errors from drive API.
        print(f'An error occurred: {error}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Assuming 'token.json' is being created it should not be requesting authorization again.  I would double check that this is in fact the code you are using, because that code is doing a file.list and looks like the standard QuickStart I don't see how you have plugged this into your upload_files method.  What is drive and where are you creating it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see you are not creating a drive service object.  In your upload files method.  Which means its not authenticated.

```
#   To install the Google client library for Python, run the following command:
#   pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client google-auth-httplib2 google-auth-oauthlib


from __future__ import print_function

import os.path
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from google.auth.exceptions import RefreshError

from googleapiclient.http import MediaFileUpload

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']

CREDENTIALS = 'C:\YouTube\dev\credentials.json'

TOKENJSON = 'tokenDriveUpload.json'

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Drive v3 API.
    Prints the names and ids of the first 10 files the user has access to.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists(TOKENJSON):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file(TOKENJSON, SCOPES)
        try:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        except RefreshError as error:
            # If the refresh token has expired then we request authorization again.
            os.remove(TOKENJSON)
            creds.refresh_token = None
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                CREDENTIALS, SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open(TOKENJSON, 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

        upload_file(creds, 'C:\YouTube\dev\logo.png')


def upload_file(creds, filepath):

    try:
        # create drive api client
        service = build('drive', 'v3', credentials=creds)

        basename = os.path.basename(filepath)
        print(basename)

        file_metadata = {'name':basename}
        media = MediaFileUpload(filepath,
                                mimetype='text/plain')

        file = service.files().create(body=file_metadata, media_body=media,
                                      fields='id').execute()

        print(F'File ID: {file.get("id")}')

    except HttpError as error:
        # TODO(developer) - Handle errors from drive API.
        print(F'An error occurred: {error}')



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```